Device Compatibility Policy When Displaying Sharepoint Site in Electron Webview
I am trying to display a sharepoint web site inside an electron application using BrowserWindow and webview.
After I login and pass MFA, it shows an error message complaining device or client application does not comply with compatibility policy and the browser is not supported. When I changed the user agent to Chrome in electron, this time it asks for Microsoft Single Sign On extension.
When we checked the requests, there's no device id set in requests that come from electron application. How can I send this device id in electron? Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

One workaround for this issue is to use a managed browser like Microsoft Edge that satisfies the approved client app and app protection policy requirements.
